# Открытие модального окна бутстрапа с помощью cookie, как?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Необходимо автоматически открыть модальное окно через 5 секунд после посещения сайта, повторное открытие через 10 дней.
Как правильно заюзать куки и модальное окно бутстрапа?

https://jsfiddle.net/4dmwp9b6/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630675/4419684

Comment: При нажатии "запустить код", код не работает, зачем ссылку тогда оставили? И вопрос был, как модал запустить через 10 секунд, и показывать его раз в 10 дней. Как бы, ответа здесь нету.

Comment: по ссылке вполне работающий код. А не запускается он в sanbox, т.к. в sandbox нельзя работать с куками у document. `Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.`

Comment: окей, щас попробую на сервере сделать, а как запустить модалку через 10 секунд после посещения сайта?

Comment: Вот в данном скрипте document.cookie = "ModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";, как установить время жизни куки 10 дней?

Comment: кто-то может помочь?

Comment: Решение, может кому-то понадобится:   var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000);
        document.cookie = "ModalShown=true; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();